# cannot resolve AppcompactActivity , symbol r , onItemSelected, getItemPosition

Tags: android

The below activity is called by another activity. The activity displays a spinner & once the user selects , the position is returned to variable p. The problems are

- cannot resolve AppActivity .
- cannot resolve symbol r.
- cannot resolve onItemSelectedListner.
- cannot resolve getItemPostion.

I have given the code below.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.exchange_input1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    public int p;

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View s1,int pos, long id)
    {
        p = getItemPosition(pos);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you face a problem like this, the most common solutions are those:

Click on **Build->Clean Project** and that will perform a gradle clean.

If this doesn't work, try:

Click on **Build->Rebuild Project**

After that, if your are still getting "cannot resolve symbol errors", try:

Click on **Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files**

If any of this worked, close Android Studio and open it again. If problems persists, please, post here if anything changed.

---

Relating to the Spinner Listener, here you have some considerations:

- You need to set the listener to your desired Spinner, in this case, "s1", e.g.:

  s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
- You can implement the OnItemSelectedListener, directly to your main
  activity

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

An then just add:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

- I can observe also, that you need to add:

  ```
  `@Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
  ```

On your public class SpinnerActivity

- Also, you don't need "getItemPosition", you can just set:

  p = pos;

Comment: I included the onNothingSelected method & tried the given options. The errors still appears.

Comment: all of them?
    cannot resolve AppActivity .
    cannot resolve symbol r.
    cannot resolve onItemSelectedListner.
    cannot resolve getItemPostion.